# Aplicação do 5S nos métodos ágeis

Tags: engenharia-de-software, metodologia, metodologia-ágil

Muito tem se falado em Scrum, XP, lean... Mas aqui no trabalho falam muito também nos 5S japoneses. Existe alguma ligação desta metodologia de trabalho para o desenvolvimento de softwares?

Comment: É, um conceito ou outro pode ter a ver. Mas o foco mesmo do 5S é organização de plantas produtivas.

Comment: Passou hoje no telecurso2000 explicação sobre isso, parece ter a ver mais com disciplina, organização do que metodologia de desenvolvimento

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A um tempo atras escrevi um post no blogue sobre o assunto:
http://gustavoemmel.blogspot.com.br/2014/07/cinco-s-kaizen-aplicados-no.html

Basicamente os 5S são:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seiri: separar;

Seiton: organizar;

Seiso: limpar;

Seiketsu: padronizar;

Shitsuke: manter;

Assim como a metodologia Lean de desenvolvimento de software e Kanban, o Kaizen também ‘nasceu’ no Japão, como parte da metodologia de trabalho da Toyota, conhecida também por Just in Time. O 5S foi e continua sendo muito usado para dar suporte a metodologias como Kanban para ajudar no processo de melhoria continua.

O conceito do 5S é para ser um método que visa organizar o local de trabalho ou um fluxo de trabalho. Uma que vez que aplicamos o Kaizen no local de trabalho, o time de colaboradores irá ter um local de trabalho mais limpo e organizado. Quando aplicado em um fluxo, qualquer colaborador poderá cumprir as etapas do mesmo e rapidamente identificar se alguma delas está faltando ou foi ‘pulada’.

Um time de desenvolvimento pode se beneficiar da pratica do Kaizen em sua rotina de trabalho, vamos olhar passo a passo como podemos aplicar em nossos projetos:

**Seiri: separar;**

Revisar nosso código antigo para remover quaisquer funções obsoletas e não mais utilizadas, bem como muitas funções que acabam não sendo mais usada e deixamos comentadas dentro do código. Muitas vezes utilizamos ferramentas de controle de versão (git), e a mesma guardará as mudanças para nós, não precisamos deixar o código comentado para ver o que se passou. Vale lembrar aqui o conceito do YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It)

**Seiton: organizar;**

Muitas vezes no desenvolvimento de software, acabamos fazendo uma força tarefa para agilizar a conclusão de determinado programa. Com essa força tarefa, acabamos fazendo certas ‘gambiarras’ para entregar o software no prazo. Devemos ter a preocupação para separar um tempo e destrinchar o código, separar bem as classes e utilizar o conceito de OO.

**Seiso: limpar;**

Importante que reservemos tempo para refatorar nosso código. Sempre que tivermos oportunidade devemos procurar melhorar e limpar um programa já desenvolvido. Mas devemos sempre nos lembrar de rodar as rotinas testes após a refatoração. Ter utilizado o TDD pode ser tornar muito útil quando for refatorar seu código.

**Seiketsu: padronizar;**

Devemos manter um padrão de codificação. Nosso código deve estar legível e de rápida compreensão. Uma ótima técnica do Extreme Programming para criar um padrão nos times de desenvolvimento é o Pair Programming.

**Shitsuke: manter;**

Uma vez que os padrões de desenvolvimento foram estabelecidos e o código foi revisado para garantir a melhor técnica e desempenho, devemos manter em alto nível tanto de nossas habilidades como desenvolvedores quanto o código desenvolvido.

Comment: Sua resposta me parece a melhor até agora, mas acho que a imagem inicial é desnecessária.

Comment: O anagrama significa o kayzem, melhoria continua. vlw pelo elogio. realmente talvez ele tenha ficado grande de mais...

Answer (score 9):

Assim como o Lean e o Kanban o 5S apareceu no japão a partir do JIT (Just in Time).

O 5S foi e ainda é muito utilizado na indústria automobilística e complementa o Kanban no sentido de manter uma perspectiva de melhora.

O Kanban foi introduzido a indústria de software por [David J. Anderson](http://www.infoq.com/articles/David-Anderson-Kanban)

## O conceito do 5S

5S é um modelo para organizar o ambiente de trabalho ou uma fábrica de manufatura etc.
A partir do momento em que o 5S é implementado no ambiente o trabalho dos funcionários fica mais limpo e organizado.

Para usar uma analogia veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Como funciona na indústria tradicional:

**1 - Organizar**
Organizar a área e elimar residuos lixos, no qual residuo pode ser uma ferramenta em local no qual a mesma não é útil.

**2 - Endireitar**

Depois do local ter sido organizado e posicionado de uma forma que o trabalho possa ser completado gerando o mínimo de resíduos possível. De forma a evitar desperdícios, se precisa de mover uma ferramenta 100 vezes no dia o ideal é que ela esteja num dos locais mais acessíveis para economizar tempo.

**3 - Polir (Brilhar)**

Garantir que o lugar esteja sempre limpo e arrumado (pronto para ser utilizado).

**4 - Padronizar**

Faça padrões para garantir que o posicionamento seja mantido.

**5 - Manter**

Verifique que os padrões estejam sendo seguidos conforme o projetado.

## Como relacionar os conceitos na *nossa indústria*:

**1 - Organizar**

Remover códigos antigos e que não estão mais em produção, se livre do que não importa mais.

**2 - Endireitar**

Às vezes na produção de software existe o conceito de : "faça isso funcionar e depois arrume para ficar *bonito*".
Separe o código com alguma forma de orientação distribuída (aspectos, objetos) para não precisar de verificar o que ocorre em um `main.c` de 20.000 linhas de código.

**3 - Polir (Brilhar)**

Permita-se tempo para refatorar o projeto e documentar as funções como algo no sentido de JavaDoc (não precisa de estar a programar em Java para manter o padrão proposto pelo JavaDoc).

**4 - Padronizar**

Se sua equipe não possui um padrão de código que deve ser seguido, não espere que um novo integrante irá analisar o código existente e tentar seguir um possível padrão.

**5 - Manter**

Uma vez que os padrões sejam definidos é importante mantê-los para garantir que a empresa continue a seguir os mesmos.

Answer (score 3):

[FONTE](http://www.sobreadministracao.com/o-que-e-a-metodologia-5s-e-como-ela-e-utilizada/)

Acredito que sim os 5s tem influencia com o desenvolvimento.
O 5s é uma metodologia, um método nos diz o que fazer e não como fazer, pense para fazer um trabalho de qualidade em equipe o que melhor que organização, padronização, utilização adequada, disciplina e limpeza, como um todo, pode existir interpretações.
Para um operário por exemplo a limpeza e organização são coisas diferentes, entendimentos diferentes a de um programador ou de um analista de suporte, mais remetem ao mesmo principio.

abaixo a definição dos 5S como na fonte;

**Princípios do 5S**

O conceito de 5S possui como base as cinco palavras japonesas cujas iniciais formam o nome do programa. As palavras são

> Seiri, Seiton, Seiso, Seiketsu e Shitsuke,

que migradas para o Português foram traduzidas como “sensos”, visando não descaracterizar a nomenclatura do programa. São eles:

> senso de utilização, senso de organização, senso de limpeza, senso de
>   saúde e senso de autodisciplina.

Vejamos separadamente os conceitos de cada um dos 5S:

**1) SEIRI – Senso de Utilização**

Significa utilizar materiais, ferramentas, equipamentos, dados, etc. com equilíbrio e bom senso. Onde é realizado o descarte ou realocação de tudo aquilo considerado dispensável para realização das atividades. Os resultados da aplicação do Senso de Utilização são imediatamente evidenciados.

Ganho de espaço
Facilidade de limpeza e manutenção
Melhor controle dos estoques
Redução de custos
Preparação do ambiente para aplicação dos demais conceitos de 5S

**2) SEITON – Senso de Organização**

O senso de organização pode ser interpretado como a importância de se ter todas as coisas disponíveis de maneira que possam ser acessadas e utilizadas imediatamente. Para isto devem-se fixar padrões e utilizar algumas ferramentas bem simples como painéis, etiquetas, estantes, etc. Tudo deve estar bem próximo do local de uso e cada objeto deve ter seu local específico. Podemos identificar como resultados do senso de organização:

Economia de tempo;
Facilidade na localização das ferramentas;
Redução de pontos inseguros.

**3) SEISO – Senso de Limpeza**

A tradução para a palavra Seiketsu é limpeza. Este senso define a importância de eliminar a sujeira, resíduos ou mesmo objetos estranhos ou desnecessários ao ambiente. Trata-se de manter o aceio do piso, armários, gavetas, estantes, etc. O senso de limpeza pode ir além do aspecto físico, abrangendo também o relacionamento pessoal onde se preserva um ambiente de trabalho onde impere a transparência, honestidade, franqueza e o respeito. A aplicação do senso de limpeza traz como resultado:

Ambiente saudável e agradável;
Redução da possibilidade de acidentes;
Melhor conservação de ferramentas e equipamentos;
Melhoria no relacionamento interpessoal.

**4) SEIKETSU – Senso de Padronização e Saúde**

O senso de padronização é traduzido na fixação de padrões de cores, formas, iluminação, localização, placas, etc. Como abrange também o conceito de saúde, é importante que sejam verificados o estado dos banheiros, refeitórios, salas de trabalho, etc. afim de que sejam identificados problemas que afetam a saúde dos colaboradores como os problemas ergonômicos, de iluminação, ventilação, etc. Este senso tem como principal finalidade manter os 3 primeiros S’ (seleção, ordenação e limpeza) de forma que eles não se percam. Podem-se evidenciar como principais resultados da aplicação deste conceito:

- Facilidade de localização e identificação dos objetos e ferramentas;
- Equilíbrio físico e mental;
- Melhoria de áreas comuns (banheiros, refeitórios, etc);
- Melhoria nas condições de segurança.

**5) SHITSUKE – Senso de Disciplina ou Autodisciplina**

A última etapa do programa 5S é definida pelo cumprimento e comprometimento pessoal para com as etapas anteriores. Este senso é composto pelos padrões éticos e morais de cada indivíduo. Esta etapa estará sendo de fato executada quando os indivíduos passam a fazer o que precisa ser feito mesmo quando não há a vigilância geralmente feita pela chefia ou quando estendem estes conceitos para a vida pessoal demonstrando seu total envolvimento. Diante de um ambiente autodisciplinado a cerca dos princípios 5S é possível que se tenha:

- Melhor qualidade, produtividade e segurança no trabalho;
- Trabalho diário agradável;
- Melhoria nas relações humanas;
- Valorização do ser humano;
- Cumprimento dos procedimentos operacionais e administrativos;

A convivência com os cinco sensos apresentados leva os indivíduos a compreenderem melhor o seu papel dentro de uma organização e os torna parte da pirâmide dos resultados alcançados, fazendo nascer a consciência de que é preciso ser disciplinado mesmo quando não há cobranças. Por isso, os Programas de Qualidade têm auxiliado as empresas no processo de melhoria contínua dos produtos ou serviços, principalmente através da mudança cultural, a fim de se obter a vantagem competitiva necessária que será colhida a curto, médio e longo prazo.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, os `5S`, no desenvolvimento de software, estão ligados diretamente ao uso da filosofia [LSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_software_development).

Assim como `Lean Software Development` e  `Kanban`, e o `5S` são sistemas `JIT` (just in time system) e você pode usá-los juntos, um complementando o outro em uma visão de melhoria contínua.